# Creating c++ code in visual studio and running it in g++

Tags: c++, g++, cross-compiling

I have created c++ code in visual studio but the university specification is that it needs to run in g++ compiler.

The code works perfectly in visual studio but does not work at all in g++. 
Why is this? 
Is there an easy way to make the code work in g++?

This is the code I have.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<long double> G;
    vector<long double> R;
    int n=1;
    long double result =1;

    R.assign(2,0);
    G.assign(2,123);
    G.at(1)=321;

    while (result >= 0.0000000000000001)
    {

    n++;    
    G.push_back((G.at(n-2) - G.at(n-1)));
    R.push_back(G.at(n)/G.at(n-1));

    result = abs(R.at(n) - R.at(n-1));

    ofstream file;
    file.open("series.txt", std ::ios_base ::app);
    file << n <<"\t" << setw(14) << G.at(n)<<"\t<<setprecision(15)<<R.at(n)<<endl;
    //cout << n <<"\t" <<setw(14)<<G.at(n)<<"\t"<<setprecision(15)<<R.at(n)<<endl;
    file.close();
    }

    system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: in order to answer this, you need to provide us the snippet of code that's failing along with the error messages.

Comment: Some additional reading: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/238689/is-there-a-difference-in-the-c-language-between-visual-studio-and-codeblocks

Comment: This isn't a _bad_ question, but you really need to add the code that isn't working, preferably a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @tas I have updated the question.

Comment: What error are you getting in gcc?

Comment: @tas the warning I am getting is missing terminating character. The error is aggregate std::ofstreamfile has incomplete type and can not be define. The other error is system was not declared in this scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for use of `system()` function you must add `#include <stdlib.h>` to your project and change

```
file << n <<"\t" << setw(14) << G.at(n)<<"\t<<setprecision(15)<<R.at(n)<<endl;
```

to

```
file << n <<"\t" << setw(14) << G.at(n)<<"\t"<<setprecision(15)<<R.at(n)<<endl;
```

then it compile 100 percentage with g++.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with cross compiling in my opinion, although to the best of my knowledge there is no `system("pause")` on linux systems.

The error is missing terminating character. Which is due to miss quotation marks at the second `\t`

This

```
file << n <<"\t" << setw(14) << G.at(n)<<"\t<<setprecision(15)<<R.at(n)<<endl;
```

should be this

```
file << n <<"\t" << setw(14) << G.at(n)<<"\t"<<setprecision(15)<<R.at(n)<<endl;
```

Comment: (Just to say, VS won't compile this either.)